# Convert numbers into word-numbers (using loop and arrays)

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, numbers, words

How do I write a simple program that converts numbers into word-numbers, using loops and arrays?

like this: input: 1532
           output: One Five Three Two

Here's what I tried:

```
class tallTilOrd 
{ 
    public static void main (String [] args) 
    { 
        Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in); 
        String [] tall = {"null", "en" , "to", "tre", "fire" , 
                          "fem", "seks", "syv", "åtte", "ni", "ti"); 
        System.out.println("Tast inn et ønsket tall"); 
        int nummer = input.nextInt(); 

        for (int i = 0; i<tall.length; i++) 
        { 
           if(nummer == i) 
           { 
              System.out.println(tall[i]); 
           } 
         } 
     } 
}
```

Comment: @MitchWheat  As 'obscure comments' go, that is right up there.

Comment: Not really. The answer is: Practice. Practice. Practice. I'm advocating the poster puts in some effort.

Comment: `if(nummer = i)`..... Are you sure you want `=`?

Comment: @ThinkPink93 In the code you provided, you need to use `==` instead of `=`. `==` is for comparison, `=` is for assignment.  Also, `println` prints a new line each time, which I imagine that you don't want.  You should probably also included spaces.  Additionally, instead of treating the number entered as an `int`, treat it as a string and then convert each character in the string into a number, which you can use to fetch the corresponding string from your array.  Instead of looping through the predefined array, loop through the input and for each character fetch the string from your array.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

```
    String in = Integer.toString(input.nextInt());
    String [] tall = {"null", "en" , "to", "tre", "fire" , "fem", "seks", "syv", "åtte", "ni", "ti"};       

    for(char c : in.toCharArray()){
        int i = (int) (c-'0');
        for (int j = 0; j<tall.length; j++) {
            if(i == j){
                System.out.print (tall[j] + " ");
            }
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

I give you a hint:

You could convert your Integer input into a String and then process each Character of that string. Check out the javadoc for [String](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html) to figure out how to do it ;-)

Now I'm not sure this is the perfect way to do it, but it would be a possible one.

Instead of iterating over the length of your `tall` array, you need to iterate over the digits of `nummer` (to do this, check out the methods `String.valueOf(int)`, `String.charAt(int)` and `String.length()`). Then use those digits as indices for `tall` to get their string representation.

Comment: I've tried coding something, buts since I'm not able to upload a picture to show you guys my code, as I'm coding on paper -.- (i's an example-exam task :/)

Comment: `I'm coding on paper`...Are you kidding?

Comment: Come on, you can just type it down. The code should not be longer than 10-15 lines.

Comment: *"I'm not able to upload a picture to show you guys my code"*  We don't want images of your code.  The text is far more important.

Comment: class tallTilOrd {
public static void main (String [] args) {
 Scanner input = new Scanner (System.in);

 String [] tall = {"null", "en" , "to", "tre", "fire" , "fem", "seks", "syv", "åtte", "ni", "ti");
 System.out.println("Tast inn et ønsket tall");

 int nummer = input.nextInt();

 for (int i = 0; i<tall.length; i++) {
  if(nummer = i) {
   System.out.println(tall[i]);
  }
 }


   
  

  }
}

Comment: @AndrewThompson it wont even let me upload this code :S Im sorry, but i'm new here...

Comment: Almost, what you want to do, is use what I just wrote in my answer. Right now you are checking if the input number is any number from your `tall` array, which is fine if you input a number between 0 and 9 ;) But what you need to do, is get the digits of `nummer` and then use those as indeces for the `tall` array.

Comment: *"it wont even let me"*  The only reason I can think that would be the case is that the code is too long.  For better help sooner, post an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/).

Comment: @ThinkPink93 All you need to do is click edit and put your code in, which I did for you.

Answer (score 0):

A few notes:

In the code you provided, you need to use `==` instead of `=`. `==` is for comparison, `=` is for assignment.

Instead of looping through the predefined array, loop through the input. Instead of treating the number entered as an `int`, treat it as a string and then convert each character in the string into a number, which you can use as an index to fetch the corresponding string from your array.

Also, note that `println` prints a newline each time.